# Proceed to postPollStatement when the result of the pollingStatement is empty (Biztalk)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

If the result of the `pollingStatement` (OracleDB Binding) in my Receive location is empty, can I proceed to the `postPollStatement` to execute an update?
It seems now it doesn't.

Comment: Is there any way you can use a Stored Procedure?  That is much better.

Comment: Stored procedures aren't an option in this case.
We need to keep the logic inside the receive port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your PolledDataAvailableStatment should look something like

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 0
  ELSE 1
  END
FROM <table>
WHERE <conditions>
```

This will a zero when there are rows and return a 1 when there are no rows.

Comment: The question is about the pollingStatement being empty. I have had cases where the PolledDataAvailableStatment returns 1 but the actual query returns no rows. i didnt need to create a file but i still needed to update the trigger table to update the flag. I solved that problem with stored procedures.